# What is this called in Python? [i.lower() for i in s if i.isalnum()]

Tags: python

```
def isPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        res = [i.lower() for i in s if i.isalnum()]
        return res==res[::-1]
```

I have seen this on a leetcode solution. What is this technique in this portion `[i.lower() for i in s if i.isalnum()]` called?

Comment: That's a list comprehension.

Comment: Check out this official doc. - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html